# Sync all tables from sqlite to postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, deployment, digital-ocean

I have a django application and deployed it on DigitalOcean. But the only problem is, new models, admin models, tables are not showing in django admin dashboard which is on running on server. Although I pushed al changes to github, pulled them from, and made migrations, again nothing changes. How can migrate all tables from db.sqlite3 to postgresql ?

Answer (score 0):

I would bet your `settings.py` database is still configured to the default sqlite.

```
# default settings.py using SQLlite
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Change that to your actual postgresql database address
Since you're deploying, it is best practice to configure those parameters as separate environnment variables, as such in your `settings.py`. Environnment variables would then have the actual values.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ['POSTGRE_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['POSTGRE_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['POSTGRE_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['POSTGRE_HOST'],
        'PORT': os.environ['POSTGRE_PORT'],
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, man, that was gunicorn reload problem. Thank you again.